# Can I run gc collect on other thread than main thread in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, garbage-collection

I tried but it seem like my ui still lagging while gc.collect. Is it possible to do? Is there some trick to do it? The main purpose is to reduce lagging while gc.collect that run automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only from C# 4.5 you can perform a [non-blocking garbage collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138633%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So it doesn't matter from which thread you are invoking collect using Unity (Mono version should correspond to C# 3 or 3.5 if I remember correctly).

It's a good practice to [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481863/unity3d-optimize-garbage-collection) as much as possible runtime allocation.

You can periodically trigger a garbage collection manually, to avoid spikes.

Answer (score 4):

That won't solve your problem. The solution is to not allocate memory during game-play. Use Object pooling instead. With Object pooling, you will be re-using the GameObjects instead of instantiating and destroying them.

**EDIT:**

Unity 2017 supports C# 4.5 so you can do this now but still, the proper solution is to use **Object pooling**. That way, you don't have to call`GC.Collect`  at-all.

Comment: Object pooling is indeed a good approach but unfortunately not always possible. Unity 2017.1 to the current 2017.2 version does support C# 4.5  but that is still in an experimental state and should be used with care.

Comment: @Acimaz It called "Experimental" because it's not implemented on some platforms yet. 4.5 has been tested extensively for over a year before it was released this year and I was one of the early testers so there should be no caution while using it. That "Experiment" word is just there so people won't blame Unity when they run into issue while using it. It works fine without any problems. Tell me where it is not possible to use Object pooling.

Comment: Yep you are right with the "experimental" thing. Was misinformed about that. Good to know though!
As for the object pooling stuff: As a developer you should know that there are too many possibilities and i cant create you one example in which it wouldnt be possible which would suffice you as a answer. But im sure there are projects not using pooling and now are not able to change that due to spaghetti code, time issues etc. etc., the stuff you have to work with as developer.
And thats why i said that its not "always" possible.